# If $dX_t=b_tdt+\sigma_tdW_t=\tilde{b}_tdt+\tilde{\sigma}_tdW_t$ then $b_t=\tilde{b}_t$ and $\sigma_t=\tilde{\sigma}_t$ a.s

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_t$ be an Ito's process where

$dX_t=b_tdt+\sigma_tdW_t=\tilde{b}_tdt+\tilde{\sigma}_tdW_t$. Prove

$b_t=\tilde{b}_t$ and $\sigma_t=\tilde{\sigma}_t$ a.s

Here my solution for $b_t=\tilde{b}_t$ a.s.

- $X_t=X_0 + \int^t_0b_sds + \int^t_0\sigma_sdW_s.$ Therefore setting $X_0=E(X_t)$ and taking the Expectation of the previous equation, $EX_t=EX_t + E\int^t_0b_sds + E\int^t_0\sigma_sdW_s \implies E\int^t_0b_sds =0$, since $E\int^t_0\sigma_sdW_s=0$

Hence doing the same for $\tilde{b}_t$, I would get $E\int^t_0b_sds =E\int^t_0\tilde{b}_sds$ therefore $E\int^t_0(\tilde{b}_s-b_s)ds=0 \implies b_t=\tilde{b}_t$ a.s

What do you think?

But then how would I prove $\sigma_t=\tilde{\sigma}_t$ a.s  ?

Comment: Why is the expectation of the first integral term 0? Are the coefficients constants? You should probably have one more step that makes it explicit that the only way the expectation of the second integral vanishes is if the difference vanishes. Should be easy to show by pulling the constants outside the expectation. For the sigma term look at the ito isometry.

Answer (score 1):

Without further assumptions on $(b_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(\tilde{b}_t)_{t \geq 0}$, the claim is not true. Consider for example

$$X_t := t = \int_0^t 1 \, ds = \int_0^t 1_{\{s \neq 1\}} \, ds$$

i.e. $\sigma_t = \tilde{\sigma}_t =0$ and $b_t = 1$, $\tilde{b}_t = 1_{\{t \neq 1\}}.$ Obviously, $$b_1 = 1 \neq 0 = \tilde{b}_1.$$

---

Some remarks concerning your proof: First of all, you cannot simply set $X_0 = \mathbb{E}(X_t)$. $X_0$ is a given random variable! Moreover, $\mathbb{E}X=0$ does not imply $X=0$ a.s.; this means that $$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^t (\tilde{b}_s-b_s) \, ds \right)=0$$ does not imply $\int_0^t \tilde{b}_s \, ds = \int_0^t b_s \, ds$ (or even $b_t = \tilde{b}_t$ a.s.).